# Jackson JSON Marshall ignore getter

Tags: json, jackson

Im using Jackson to convert a POJO into a JSON to store in the DB. However I have a getter that I want to ignore. I have see a lot of info relating to @JsonIgnoreProperties but I can't seem to make any progress with it. I basically want the equivalent of @Transient.

Basic usecase (I want to ignore the InternationalNumber):

```
public class PhoneNumber {

private String country;
private String number;

public PhoneNumber() {}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getLocalNumber() {
    return localNumber;
}

public String getInternationalNumber() {
    String result = "Not Available";
    if (country != null && localNumber != null) {
    result = new PhoneNumberHandler().internationalFormat(
            localNumber, WorldCountries.countryToIso2Code(country));
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

That would be [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) on getter method.

Comment: @Ogen should work; if not, subtype not being seen for some reason.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by subtype? My example is the same as this question. I have a getter method with no property associated, the only difference is that the method is overridden.

Comment: @Ogen subtype as in sub-class or sub-interface. Annotations can only have effect when code sees them: so one common problem is that type given is of super-type (without annotation), and not sub-type (which has annotation). Otherwise, if annotated type seen, would sound like a bug.